# Save some arrays in a same file

Tags: python, numpy, save

I would like to save different arrays in the same file:

```
a = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
b = [1,3,5]
```

I read this [documentation](http://www.djmannion.net/psych_programming/fundamentals/arrays/arrays.html#loading-and-saving-arrays-from-to-disk) about the `np.savetxt` function

Nevertheless, I can't save `a` and `b` in the same file to access to them in an other programm.

I would like something like this:

```
a = load("file_path",a)
b = load("file_path",b)
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html

Comment: Why you didn't save the arrays an array which contains two arrays two the file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `np.savez` instead

```
np.savez("file_path.npz", a=a, b=b)
```

And then load with

```
npzfile = np.load(outfile)

a = npzfile['a']
b = npzfile['b']
```

EDIT: Updated `np.savez` call, so arrays are saved with their own names.

Comment: I executed your code, but the files in the archive are not named correctly. So, when I want to load them, I have the following error: `KeyError:'b is not a file in the archive'`. How to name them correctly when they are saved ?

Comment: np.savez("file_path.npz", a=a, b=b)